# Python/Scapy: sniff only incoming packets

Tags: python, scapy

Can I sniff only incoming or only outgouing packets in Scapy?

Without addition of filters on packet fields.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no. Scapy's sniff function doesn't distinguish between incoming and outgoing packets. If you want to filter based on source mac, you can do this:

```
MYMAC = "12:34:56:78:90:99"

def isNotOutgoing(pkt):
    return pkt[Ether].src != MYMAC

sniff(iface="eth0", lfilter=isNotOutgoing)
```

Comment: To retrieve the MAC address automatically you can do `sniff(iface="eth0", lfilter=lambda pkt: pkt[Ether].src != Ether().src)`

Answer (score 1):

As for Scapy version 2.4.3, I can filter inbound traffic for analysis. For example, the following command can be used to filter inbound traffic on the interface "eth0":

```
sniff(iface="eth0", filter="inbound", prn=lambda x: x.show(), store=0)
```

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453283/filter-options-for-sniff-function-in-scapy), sniff() uses Berkeley Packet Filter (BPF) [syntax](https://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html).
Conceivably, one can filter only outbound traffic by `filter="outbound"`; without the filter argument, it is equivalent as `filter="inbound or outbound"`.

Answer (score 0):

sniff() supports all L2socket arguments.  One such argument is filter, which takes a BPF filter http://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html.  In some situations, this include the 'incoming' filter.

Comment: Even though is answer is good, in the future consider posting a sample of working code rather than a link. Links can break in the future ;)

Comment: I could like this answer if it provided working code ;)

Answer (score -1):

Scapy doesn't always perform best: http://askldjd.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/a-reasonably-fast-python-ip-sniffer/

However you can definitely sniff incoming and outgoing. I am not aware of a way to take in only incoming or outgoing specifically but I believe you can filter your results. Or if you are willing to take on a larger task you can edit Scapy and create your own sniffer that only takes in one or the other.