# Filter options for sniff function in scapy

Tags: python, linux, networking, ethernet, scapy

I'm working on a scapy based tool where at a point I need to sniff a packet based on protocol and the ip address of the destination

I'd like to know about the ways in which filter option in sniff() function can be used. I tried using format in documentation but most of the times it results in problems like this.
[the filter of sniff function in scapy does not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095701/the-filter-of-sniff-function-in-scapy-does-not-work-properly) .

The one which I used was

```
a=sniff(filter="host 172.16.18.69 and tcp port 80",prn = comp_pkt,count = 1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`sniff()` uses Berkeley Packet Filter (BPF) [syntax](http://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html) (the same one as `tcpdump`), here are some examples:

Packets from or to host:

```
host x.x.x.x
```

Only TCP SYN segments:

```
tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn != 0
```

Everything ICMP but echo requests/replies:

```
icmp[icmptype] != icmp-echo and icmp[icmptype] != icmp-echoreply
```